# Why is my Rails Minitest Polymorphic Failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, minitest

I have these models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :setting, as: :resource, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :services
end

class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and I have this code snippet from a controller  to access them, which works when manually testing (this is a before_action method):

```
before_action :setup

def get_vars
  @setting = Setting.find_by_booking_url @url
  @user = @setting.resource
  @services = @user.services
end

def setup
  @url = params[:url]
  @setting = Setting.find_by_url @url
  @user = @setting.resource
end
```

but when using automated testing with these fixtures:

```
# fixtures/users.yml
james:
  email: 'james@example.com'
  first_name: 'James'
  last_name: 'Soften'
  encrypted_password: <%= default_password_digest %>

# fixtures/settings.yml
scott_settings:
  resource: james (User)
  time_zone: 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
  url: 'urlsegment'
```

and this controller test code:

```
setup do
  @user = users(:james)
end
def test_booking_page_success
  get :new, url: @user.setting.url
  assert_response :success
end
```

it fails with error:

```
undefined method `services` for nil:NilClass
```

which indicates that I cannot access "resource" to get the User from the Setting object.

I checked the variables using byebug (in the middle of running tests) and the Setting object (@user.setting) has a resource_id and resource_name, so I was wondering why I cannot access the user from the Setting object using "resource" attribute when running the tests.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT: added more controller code**

**EDIT: added URL field in settings fixture**

Comment: is it just me or is it possible that  `@user = @setting.resource` doesn't make sense? in the get vars method.. It may not fail during manual testing for different reasons?

Comment: Can you update with the part of your controller that sets the ``@url`` instance variable?

Comment: Would it be a problem in your `scott_setting` fixture? The resource is simpy `james`. I guess it should be a primary key for the `User` model. What does simple SQL tells you?

Comment: @EricPlaton [no](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Fixtures.html), fixture defined just as doc says, actually all code here works correctly, I reproduced the app looking for errors, it's something that is not here...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following before test_booking_page_success

```
def test_url
 assert_not_empty @user.setting.url
end
```

You are probably passing an empty 'url' parameter... if the fixtures shown are complete and you are not generating url from something else.

**Upd** The only scenario I can imagine: is that booking_url in scott_settings is set to something other than 'urlsegment' in your fixtures. So it returns other settings with nil resource...

Comment: added this test. it passed

Comment: hmm, strange, created a test setup with a structure of your app, but can't make it fail the test... which version of rails are you using? (I've done this on 4.2.0)

Comment: Did some research... nothing, just can confirm this code works, both under auto- and manual testing. Only thing i can't check is  `@setting = Setting.find_by_booking_url @url`, but if you checked with byebug...

Comment: I even couldn't brake the fixtures to get this error - no users -> `StandardError: No fixture named 'john' found for fixture set 'users'` - no settings -> `NoMethodError: undefined method 'url' for nil:NilClass`, no services -> test passes...

Comment: The only scenario I can imagine: is that booking_url in scott_settings is set to something other than 'urlsegment' in your fixtures. So it returns other settings with nil resource...